# how to check how many file names start with certain chars?

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone app that saves some people's data on a single file. Each filename is represented by the user name plus an incremental number, say "tommy1", "tommy2",... , "tommy32", then "sarah1", "sarah2", and so on.

Is it possible to count how many of them are "tommy"'s and how many are "sarah"'s from within the code ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

[-[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW6)

and

[-[NSString hasPrefix:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-hasPrefix_)

and perhaps [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).